# how to compute the last 2 digits of $3^{3^{3^{3}}}$ to n times?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Input $n$, output the last $2$ digits of the result.

```
n=1 03 3=3  
n=2 27 3^3=27  
n=3 87 3^27=7625597484987
n=4 ?? 3^7625597484987=??
```

Sorry guys, the formula given is $T_n=3^{T_{n-1}}$, I have updated the example.
I was asked this question during an interview, but I didn't have any clue. (The interviewer kind of gave me a hint that for $n>10$, the last $10$ digits of all results would be the same?)

Comment: you sure you meant 3^3 = 09? for n=2

Comment: yeah, should be 27, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: 3^3^3^3 is not 7625597484987

Comment: You need to put some parentheses there. $3^{3^3}\neq \left(3^3\right)^3$ . So this is just $3^{3n}$. Do you have some idea about Modular Arithmetic?

Comment: @bobbym Yes it is. It's ((3^3)^3)^3

Comment: @Thanos Darkadakis, when you put the brackets then yes. But not when you leave them out. $3^{3^{3^3}} > 10^{1000000000000}$

Comment: I figured out the brackets from n=3

Comment: @Kailas, yes that is what he meant but not what he is posting. Just pointing out that power towers are evaluated from the top down.

Comment: Yes, each time there is one more cube outside. I was asked this question during an interview, but I didn't have any clue. (The interviewer kind of gave me a hint that for n>10, the last 10 digits of all results would be the same?)

Comment: More generally: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699828

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice $$3^{100} = 515377520732011331036461129765621272702107522001 \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$$
If we define $p_n$ such that $p_1 = 3$ and $p_n = 3^{p_{n-1}}$ recursively and
split $p_n$ as $100 q_n + r_n$ where $q_n, r_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $0 \le r_n < 100$, we have

$$p_n = 3^{p_{n-1}} = 3^{100 q_{n-1} + r_{n-1}} \equiv 1^{q_{n-1}}3^{r_n} \equiv 3^{r_{n-1}} \pmod{100} \\ \implies r_n \equiv 3^{r_{n-1}} \pmod{100}$$

This means to obtain $r_n$, the last two digit of $p_n$, we just need to start with
$r_1 = 3$ and repeat iterate it. We find 
$$\begin{align}
r_1 &= 3\\
r_2 &\equiv 3^3 = 27 \pmod{100}\\
r_3 &\equiv 3^{3^3} = 7625597484987 \equiv 87 \pmod{100}
\end{align}$$

Notice 
$$3^{87} = 323257909929174534292273980721360271853387 \equiv 87 \pmod{100}$$

So after the third (not fourth) iteration, we have $r_n = 87$ for all $n \ge 3$.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the answer, still trying to understand

Comment: Got it! Thanks everyone.

Comment: A remark: This would happen for any other base and modulus, not just $3$ and $100$ . Since $f(n)=b^n\pmod k$ has periodicity $<k$, the periodicity for each level of the power tower is always less than the previous one, and we would eventually reach periodicity one, guaranteeing that eventually the sequence will "stall".

Comment: In particular, the periods here happen to be $20,4,2,1$ (because $3^{20}\equiv1\pmod{100}, 3^4\equiv1\pmod{20}, 3^2\equiv1\pmod4,3\equiv1\pmod2$ )

Answer (score 4):

These are the last 2 digits of $3^m$ for $m\in\{0..19\}$

```
01,03,09,27,81,43,29,87,61,83,49,47,41,23,69,07,21,63,89,67
Let's call this A: A[0]=01, A[1]=03, A[19]=67...
```

These numbers are repeated for every 20 numbers. i.e. $3^{20+x}$ mod 100=$3^x$ mod 100

Your sequence of numbers simplified is: $3^{3^{n-1}}$.

For example for n=4: $a_4=((3^3)^3)^3=(3^3)^{3*3}=3^{3*3*3}$ using that $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$

So, you just have to find the exponent modulo 20. i.e $3^{n-1}$ mod 20

These are the remainder (modulo 20) of $3^m$ for $m\in\{0..3\}$

```
1,3,9,7
```

These numbers are repeated for every 4 numbers. i.e. $3^{4+x}$ mod 20=$3^x$ mod 20

So what you need is:

- A[1]=03 (=B[1])
- A[3]=27 (=B[2])
- A[9]=83 (=B[3])
- A[7]=87 (=B[0])

These numbers are repeated. So in order to find an answer for a given n, you will have to compute n mod 4 and then get B[n mod 4].

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, could you please help me the updated question? formula is T(n)=3^(T(n-1))

Comment: I added an example of why this is true for n=4. You can make generic for n

Answer (score 2):

There is a stronger argument:

---

$3^{100}\equiv 1 \pmod{1000}$ and by induction

> **Proposition 1.** $3^{10^{n}}\equiv 1 \pmod{10^{n+1}}$, $\forall n \geq 2$

Because:
$$3^{10^{n+1}}-1=3^{10 \cdot 10^{n}}-1=(3^{10^{n}}-1)\cdot(3^{9 \cdot 10^{n}} + 3^{8 \cdot 10^{n}} + ... + 3^{1 \cdot 10^{n}} + 1)=(3^{10^{n}}-1)\cdot(3^{9 \cdot 10^{n}}-1 + 3^{8 \cdot 10^{n}}-1 + ... + 3^{1 \cdot 10^{n}}-1 + 10)$$

---

Obviously, this also implies

> **Proposition 2.** $3^{10^{n}}\equiv 1 \pmod{10^{n}}, \forall n \geq 2$

---

Next thing to observe is:

> **Proposition 3.** If $3^{x}\equiv y \pmod{10^{n}}$ $\Rightarrow $ $3^{3^{x}} \equiv 3^{y} \pmod{10^{n+1}}$, $\forall n\geq 2$

Because, from $3^{x}=10^{n} \cdot q +y$ $\Rightarrow$ $3^{3^{x}} = 3^{10^{n} \cdot q +y}$ and using first result $3^{10^{n} \cdot q} \equiv 1^{q} \equiv 1 \pmod{10^{n+1}}$ we have $3^{3^{x}} \equiv 3^{y} \pmod{10^{n+1}}$.

---

Now, that $t_{3} \equiv 87 \pmod{100}$ $\Rightarrow$ $t_{4} \equiv 3^{87} \pmod{1000}$ and (easy to show) $3^{87} \equiv 387 \pmod{1000}$, i.e. $t_{4} \equiv 387 \pmod{1000}$.

Also $t_{5} = 3^{t_{4}} \equiv 3^{1000 \cdot q + 387} \equiv 3^{387} \equiv 3^{100 \cdot 3 + 87} \equiv 3^{87} \equiv 387 \pmod{1000}$.

As a result, $$t_{5} \equiv t_{4} \pmod{10^3}$$
$$t_{6} \equiv t_{5} \pmod{10^4}$$
$$t_{7} \equiv t_{6} \pmod{10^5}$$
$$...$$
and by induction

> $$t_{n+2} \equiv t_{n+1} \pmod{10^{n}}$$

But we can stop at:
$$t_{12} \equiv t_{11} \pmod{10^{10}}$$
$$t_{13} \equiv t_{12} \pmod{10^{11}}\Rightarrow t_{13} \equiv t_{12} \pmod{10^{10}}\Rightarrow t_{13} \equiv t_{11} \pmod{10^{10}}$$
$$...$$

That's, more or less, the proof for "*(The interviewer kind of gave me a hint that for $n>10$, the last $10$ digits of all results would be the same?)*"

Comment: Can you prove that $t_{n+2} \equiv t_{n+1} \pmod{10^{n}}$ holds every time

Comment: @SohamChatterjee the proof is provided in the answer. Or that wasn't a question?