# Prove that $1989\mid n^{n^{n^{n}}} - n^{n^{n}}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Having difficulty in proving this: $1989\mid n^{n^{n^{n}}} - n^{n^{n}}$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Prime factorization of $1989$ is $3^2 \times 13 \times 17$.

Please Help!

Comment: TeX tip: Use `\mid` for "divides" instead of `|`. Compare $a \mid b$ to $a|b$. And of course there's also `\nmid`: $a \nmid b$.

Comment: @user8795: I think you need to modify your conjecture to $1989 \mid n^{n^{n^n}}-n^{n^n}$ for all integer $\color{blue}{n>2}$. I've tested it with Wolfie and it is true for $2<n<20$ so far. If it is false, then it should be interesting to know the first $n>2$ that it fails.

Comment: Related: [Last digits of power towers $7$, $7^7$, $7^{7^7}$, $7^{7^{7^7}}$, ... don't change, and generalisation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699828)

Comment: I have posted an answer to [this related (almost duplicate) question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288942/1989-mid-nnnn-nnn-for-integer-n-ge-3). I do not know whether it is correct, though.

Answer (score 11):

This wrong for $n=2,\;$ because $1989$ does not divide $2^{2^{2^{2}}} - 2^{2^{2}}=2^{16}-16=65520$.