# $1989 \mid n^{n^{n^{n}}} - n^{n^{n}}$ for integer $n \ge 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Before anyone comments, yes this is kind of a duplicate of [Prove that $1989\mid n^{n^{n^{n}}} - n^{n^{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171694/prove-that-1989nnnn-nnn) . The problem that I'm having I don't see the $n=5$ as a counterexample. Also if anyone wants to know where I got this problem from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.muni.cz%2F~bulik%2Fvyuka%2Fpen-20070711.pdf&ei=a-pXVfuOEsm-sAWr5ICoBg&usg=AFQjCNESVFKertjKo1RRDenoVvOsgsul0w&sig2=vU0d9wa2LQ51WWsgH0873Q).

I'm looking at the problem $\color{red} {\text{A10}}$. This is not a homework. This is a question I chose to do for fun and I'm totally not sure how to do this problem after playing with for hours. I have made a conjecture that I cannot prove. I believe $n^n \equiv k \mod 1989$ while $n^{n^n} \equiv k \mod 1989$ while $n^{n^{n^n}}\equiv k \mod 1989$ for integer $n \ge 4$. Anyways right now I'm just looking for a hint. I still want to try. You can put spoilers in your answers if you want to. Also we can use whatever we want to prove this. Though I do warn you my number theory skills are still a work in progress. And what I'm looking for is to prove this: $1989 \mid n^{n^{n^{n}}} - n^{n^{n}}$ for integer $n \ge 3$

Comment: $n=5$ is not a counterexample.

Comment: I agree Ross . Also @anon $k$ is an integer. For example. $5^5 \equiv 1136 , 5^{5^5} \equiv 1136, 5^{5^{5^5}} \equiv 1136$ all mod 1989.

Comment: So then say $n^n\equiv n^{n^n}\equiv n^{n^{n^n}}$ mod $1989$ to communicate your conjecture.

Comment: Right. I just wrote it like a system of equations just in case there was someway to do this with that Chinese theorem.

Comment: @randomgirl: I don't think math110's answer is conclusive yet until he addresses a month-old comment/counter-example.

Comment: Are you born in 1989 ? :)

Answer (score 4):

> **Lemma 1**
>   $$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0} \hspace{1.5em} n^{n^n} \equiv n^n \pmod3 $$

This is trivial.

> **Lemma 2**
>   $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{1.5em} n\ge 3 \implies n^{n^n} \equiv n^n \pmod{16} $$

*Proof*. If $n$ is even, then $n\ge4$ and thus $16 \mid n^n, n^{n^n}$. If $n$ is congruent to $\pm 1$ modulo $16$, the proposition above holds. Then, we only need to check $\pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 7$. By Euler's theorem,
\begin{align}
n\equiv 3 \pmod{16} \implies 3^{n^n} - 3^n &\equiv 3^{n^n-n \pmod8}-1 \\
&\equiv 3^{3^{n\pmod4}-3}-1 \\
&\equiv 3^{3\cdot 8} -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{16}
\end{align}
  \begin{align}
n\equiv 5 \pmod{16} \implies 5^{n^n} - 5^n &\equiv 5^{n^n-n \pmod8}-1 \\
&\equiv 5^{5^{n\pmod4}-5}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{16}
\end{align}
  \begin{align}
n\equiv 7 \pmod{16} \implies 7^{n^n} - 7^n &\equiv 7^{n^n-n \pmod8}-1 \\
&\equiv 7^{7^{n\pmod4}+1}-1 \\
&\equiv 7^{7^3+1} -1 \equiv 7^{43\cdot 8} -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{16}
\end{align}
The cases $-3,-5,-7$ are now trivial.

> **Theorem**
>   $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{1.5em} n\ge 3 \implies n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{1989} $$

*Proof*. We first split the congruence as follows.
$$\begin{align} n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{1989} &\iff \begin{cases}
n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{9} \\
n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{13} \\
n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{17}
\end{cases} 
\end{align}$$
Since $2,2,3$ are primitive roots of $9,13,17$ respectively, then
$$\begin{align}
n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{9} &\iff \begin{cases}  n^{n^n}\cdot\operatorname{ind}_2n \equiv n^n\cdot\operatorname{ind}_2n \pmod{6} & 3 \nmid n \\ 0 \equiv 0 & 3 \mid n\end{cases} \\[1ex]
n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{13} &\iff \begin{cases}  n^{n^n}\cdot \operatorname{ind}_2n \equiv n^n \cdot\operatorname{ind}_2n \pmod{12} & 13 \nmid n \\ 0 \equiv 0 & 13 \mid n\end{cases} \\[1ex]
n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{17}  &\iff \begin{cases}  n^{n^n}\cdot \operatorname{ind}_3n \equiv n^n \cdot\operatorname{ind}_3n \pmod{16} & 17 \nmid n \\ 0 \equiv 0 & 17 \mid n\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
By the lemmas, these congruences hold for all $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Note $1989=3^2\cdot 13\cdot 17$. Use [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) (a.k.a. [Euler's totient theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html)), namely, let $\varphi(n)$ be the *totient function*, then,

$$a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 (\text{mod}\, n)$$

for all $a$ relatively prime to $n$. We then have the following result:
$$m|n^a-n^b\Longleftrightarrow \varphi(m)|(a-b),\;\rm{gcd}(n,m)=1\tag1$$
Since $\rm{lcm}[\varphi(3^2),\varphi(13),\varphi(17)]=2^4\cdot 3$,
so we only prove
$$2^4 \cdot3|(n^{n^n}-n^n)$$
and $\rm{lcm}[\varphi(2^4),\varphi(3)]=8$
we only prove
$$8|n^n-n$$
where $n$ is odd. It is clear.

Comment: No, $m\mid n^a-n^b\iff \text{ord}_m (n)\mid a-b$, but $\text{ord}_m (n)$ is not necessarily equal to $\varphi(m)$ when $(n,m)=1$. E.g. obviously $m\mid 1^a-1^b$ for any $a,b,m$, but we don't always have $\varphi(m)\mid a-b$. Another example: $5\mid 4^4-4^2$, but we don't have $5\mid 4-2$.

Comment: As mentioned above $n=4,m=5,a=4,b=2$ is a counter-example to your first claim.

Comment: @math110: I've filled in some details of your post, but you need to clarify your claim $(1)$  since _user26486_ pointed out a counter-example. Otherwise, this answer doesn't seem to be conclusive yet.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I have unaccepted this answer. I had put this question on the back burner for a long time. I think it was a question I wasn't really prepared for, didn't have the proper background. If you can offer a better solution, I will accept it.