# Last digit of large powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Define the sequence $a_1, a_2,...$ by $a_1=7$ and where $a_{n+1} = a_n^7$.

1) Find the last digit of $a_{1876}$, ie $7(^7)(^7)(^7)(^7)(^...)$

Now, I understand that the last digit of powers of 7 repeat every 4 powers (i think), so the answer has something to do with integers modulo 4. While I was working on this, I found than $a_n$ can be written as $a_n = 7^{(7^{n-1})}$, not sure if this is correct or if it helps.

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions. You can read about the last digits of $b_n$ here: [Last digits of power towers $7$, $7^7$, $7^{7^7}$, $7^{7^{7^7}}$, ... don't change, and generalisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699828/last-digits-of-power-towers-7-77-777-7777-dont-chan)

Answer (score 2):

The order of $7$ mod $100$ is $4$, i.e. $7^4 = 2401 \equiv 1 \mod 100$, so $7^{4i+j} \equiv 7^j (\bmod 100)$ for any integers $i$ and $j$.
Since $4$ divides $100$, this is also true mod $4$.

Now $a_n = 7^{7^{n-1}}$, and $2008$ is divisible by $4$ so $7^{2008} \equiv 7^0 = 1 (\bmod 4)$, and $a_{2009} \equiv 7^{1} = 7 (\bmod 100)$.

As for $b_{2009}$, we have $b_1 = 7 \equiv 3 (\bmod 4)$, and since $3^3 = 27 \equiv 3 (\bmod 4)$ we get $b_n \equiv 3 (\bmod 4)$ for all $n \ge 1$,
and so for $n \ge 2$, $b_n \equiv 7^{b_{n-1}} \equiv 7^3 \equiv 43 (\bmod 100)$.

Comment: @ Robert Israel So are you saying the last digit of $a_{2009}$ is 7 and the last digit of $b_{2009}$ is 3?

Comment: The last two digits of $a_{2009}$ are $07$, and the last two digits of $b_{2009}$ are $43$.

Comment: You're missing a lot of steps in your proofs.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How would you go about finding the last digit of $a_{2009}$ and $b_{2009}$? I was more confused with that part funnily enough.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the powers of $7$ have the last digit $7-9-3-1.$The last digit of $7^7=a_2$ is $3.$

For the powers of $3$ is the last digit $3-9-7-1.$ So the last digit of $a_3$ is $7.$

Can you finish for $a_{2009}?$

Comment: Apart from using a calculator, how did you find the last digit of $a_2$ to be 3? Then the last digit of $a_3$ to be 7?