# If $T_1=7^7,T_2=7^{7^{7}},T_3=7^{7^{7^{7}}}$ and so on, what will be the tens digit of $T_{1000}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$7^4$ ends with $2301$, so $7^{4k+r}$ ends with $7^r$ digits

$7^2\equiv1 \mod(4) $, and $7^7\equiv 3 \mod(4) $

Can we use the modulo function in exponent form? I think we will use these two properties, how can I proceed further?

Comment: That's a good start.  After that, just note that we only care about $T_n\pmod {100}$.

Comment: Note:  should add that I am reading the recursion as $T_{n+1}=7^{T_n}$.

Comment: @Lulu, yes you are reading it correctly

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699828/last-digits-of-power-towers-7-77-777-7777-dont-chan) should help.

Comment: $7^4=24\color{blue}{01}\equiv1\bmod100$. So you may not have very many residues $\bmod100$ to sort through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i correctly understand the question, we have to compute the value of $T_{1000}$ modulo $100$.

*Long solution*:
This is done in a few steps applying at each one the Euler indicator function $\varphi$, noting that basis $7$ is relatively prime to each of the numbers $\varphi(100)=40$, $\varphi(40)=16$, $\varphi(16)=8$ and so on, if we really need to so deeper...

---

We have for some *odd* power $N$ the relation
$$7^N=(8-1)^N\equiv(-1)^N\equiv -1\pmod8\ $$
Computations have been done in the units group of the ring $\Bbb Z/8$.

---

The above implies
$$
7^{7^N}
\equiv 7^{7^N\pmod {\varphi(16)}}
\equiv 7^{7^N\pmod 8}
\equiv 7^{-1}
\equiv 7\pmod{16}\ .
$$
Computations have been done in the units group of the ring $\Bbb Z/16$.

---

The above implies
$$
7^{7^{7^N}}
\equiv 7^{7^{7^N}\pmod {\varphi(40)}}
\equiv 7^{7^{7^N}\pmod {16}}
\equiv 7^7
\equiv 7\cdot 49^3
\equiv 7\cdot 9^3
\equiv 7\cdot 9\cdot 81
\equiv 7\cdot 9\cdot 1
\equiv 63
\equiv 23\pmod{40}\ .
$$
Computations have been done in the units group of the ring $\Bbb Z/40$.

---

The above implies finally
$$
7^{7^{7^{7^N}}}
\equiv 7^{7^{7^{7^N}}\pmod {\varphi(100)}}
\equiv 7^{7^{7^{7^N}}\pmod{40}}
\equiv 7^{23}
\equiv 7^3\cdot (7^4)^5
\equiv 7^3\cdot 2401^5
\equiv 7^3\cdot 1^5
\equiv 7^3
\equiv 343\equiv 63
\equiv 43\pmod{100}\ .
$$
Computations have been done in the units group of the ring $\Bbb Z/100$.

$\square$

---

*Short solution*: The above procedure is designed to work in general, this is written so for didactic purposes. In our case however, we finally need the power of an element of multiplicative order $4$ in $\Bbb Z/100$. So we need in fact in  $T_{1000}=7^{7^{\text{et caetera}}}$ only the value of
$7^{\text{et caetera}}$ modulo four. This is $-1$ (as computed even modulo $8$). So we need $7^{-1}$ in $\Bbb Z/100$. This is $43$.

Comment: what do you mean by ring z/8, and what is a ring

Comment: The "ring" $\Bbb Z/n$ is the structure of the integers taken modulo the integer number $n\ne 0$, this structure allows all arithmetic operations, excepting division. So we can add, subtract, multiply, we have a zero element, the class of zero modulo $n$, a one element, the class of one modulo $n$, and all computations with numbers modulo $n$ are done by "lifting" to (the ring) $\Bbb Z$, computing there, and taking modulo $n$ back again. Now a part of $\Bbb Z/n$ builds a "group" w.r.t. multiplication, these are all elements like $k\pmod n$, where $k$ is relatively prime to $n$. It is import...

Comment: ... it is important to see this group structure, since this is the structure allowing to "take modulus in the power", namely modulo the "order" of the group of these $k$ modulo $n$, which is $\varphi(n)$. I always give the structural answer, even if this requires learning the structure. Well, this time it is of crucial importance to think structurally, this will solve many problems in number theory (using in fact a simple structure)... See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Example:_Integers_modulo_4

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments observe that $T_n = 7^{T_n}$.
We use induction to find tens digits of $T_n$.

Observe that $T_1 = 43 \mod 100$.

Assume that $T_n \equiv 43\mod 100$. So write $T_n = 43 + 100k$ for some $k$

So $T_{n+1} \mod 100 = 7^{T_n} \mod 100 = 7^{43} 7^{100k} \mod 100$.

Now see that $7^4 = 1 \mod 100$ so we have $7^{100k} = 1 \mod 100$ and $7^{43} \equiv 7^3 \equiv 43 \mod 100$. So we get $T_{n+1} \equiv 43 \mod 100$

So we have $T_n \equiv 43 \mod 100$ for all $n$. This means that tens digit of $T_n$ will be $43$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can repeatedly apply Euler's theorem. This works because: $$a^{b^c}=a^{\left(b^c\right )}=(a^{b)\dots^b}$$
where the parenthesized exponentiation has
c parenthesization levels.  so you mod all $b$ by $\phi(n)$ then reverse the parenthesized exponentiation to unparenthesized exponentiation. Realizing equivalences in exponents mod $\phi(n)$ will reduce the next and so on.